# Importing a contact in Xamarin - emails return null

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am attempting to import a selected contact from the phone directory into my app. Using my code below, The contact name and phone number return successfully, but email always return null (the `if (emailCursor.MoveToFirst())` clause always returns false). The ImportedContact is a simple class with 3 string properties, Name, Phone and Email. I've made sure my contact has an email address assigned.

```
static ImportedContact GetContactFromUri(Android.Net.Uri contactUri)
        {
            var importedContact = new ImportedContact();

            try
            {
                string[] projection =
                {
                    ContactsContract.Contacts.InterfaceConsts.Id,
                    ContactsContract.Contacts.InterfaceConsts.DisplayName,
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.Number
                };

                var cursor = CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity.ContentResolver.Query(contactUri, projection, null, null, null);
                if (cursor.MoveToFirst())
                {
                    importedContact.Name = cursor.GetString(cursor.GetColumnIndex(projection[1]));
                    importedContact.Phone = cursor.GetString(cursor.GetColumnIndex(projection[2]));
                };

                var id = cursor.GetString(cursor.GetColumnIndex(projection[0]));
                var emailCursor = CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity.ContentResolver.Query(
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.ContentUri,
                    null,
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.InterfaceConsts.ContactId + " = " + id, null, null);

                if (emailCursor.MoveToFirst())
                {
                    int colId = emailCursor.GetColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.InterfaceConsts.Data);
                    importedContact.Email = emailCursor.GetString(colId);
                }
                emailCursor.Close();

                return importedContact;
            }
            catch
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Looking at your code to fetch the email it looks ok to me. All I can say is make double sure that the Contact that is coming in the first query does really has an email assigned.

Comment: Thanks @pinedax for confirming that, I was fixated on this code for a while and have discovered the actual issue was due to the way I was calling the picker - I was setting the intent type as `Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionPick);
         intent.SetType(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.ContentType);` when I should have instead used `Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionPick, ContactsContract.Contacts.ContentUri);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual issue was due to to the way I was calling the picker - I was incorrectly setting the intent type as specific to phone data:

```
public static void OpenContactPicker(Action<ImportedContact> callback)
{
    _callback = callback;
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionPick);
    intent.SetType(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.ContentType);
    CurrentActivity.StartActivityForResult(intent, RequestCodes.ContactPicker);
}
```

and this was returning only the phone information and excluding the emails, website, etc. I changed this to:

```
    public static void OpenContactPicker(Action<ImportedContact> callback)
    {
        _callback = callback;
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionPick, ContactsContract.Contacts.ContentUri);
        CurrentActivity.StartActivityForResult(intent, RequestCodes.ContactPicker);
    }
```

and this is returning all the contact information as required.

Comment: Thanks for your sharing, please do not forget to accept your answer.